# button in child component does not show up

Tags: angular

as shown below i have a component named `Treatment-as-tiff` and in its html file there should be a button. that button should be visible when specific action occures in `site-map-component`.the problem is when i run the code
and set that action to occure the button does not show up

please let me know what i am missing here

**TreatmentAsTIFF html**:

```
<button  *ngIf="iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser.visibilityState" 
    title="Get Treatment As TIFF" 
    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" 
    (click)="getTreatmentAsTIFF()">
    {{ "SITE.GET_TREATMENT_AS_TIFF" | translate }}
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

**TreatmentAsTIFF.ts**:

```
import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SYNOPSServicesProviderService} from '../services/SYNOPSServiceProvider/synopsservices-provider.service'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


export interface ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser {
  visibilityState: boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-treatment-as-tiff',
  templateUrl: './treatment-as-tiff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./treatment-as-tiff.component.css']
})
export class TreatmentAsTIFFComponent implements OnInit {
  iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser:ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;
  subscriptionEvtEmitterOnTratmentAsTIFFEmitted: Subscription;

  constructor(private synopsServicesProvider:SYNOPSServicesProviderService) { 
    this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser = {} as ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;
    this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser.visibilityState = false
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.subscriptionEvtEmitterOnTratmentAsTIFFEmitted = this.synopsServicesProvider.getEventEmitterResponseFoRiskCalculation().subscribe((response: object)=> {
      console.log("OnTratmentAsTIFF response received: ",response)
     });
  }

  public getVisibilityState() {
    return this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser.visibilityState;
  }
  public setInvisible() {
    this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser.visibilityState = false
  }
  public setVisible() {
    this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser.visibilityState = true
  }
  
    private getTreatmentAsTIFF(fieldGeometry):void{
        this.synopsServicesProvider.startWebServiceForGetTreatmentAsTIFF(fieldGeometry);
    }
}
```

**site-map-component**:

```
import { TreatmentAsTIFFComponent } from '../treatment-as-tiff/treatment-as-tiff.component';

export interface ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser {
    visibilityState: boolean
}

iTreatmentAsTIFFButtonVisibilityPasser:ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;
treatmentAsTIFFComponent: TreatmentAsTIFFComponent;

constructor() {
        this.iTreatmentAsTIFFButtonVisibilityPasser = {} as ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;
        this.iTreatmentAsTIFFButtonVisibilityPasser.visibilityState = false
    }
...
...
...
private toggleGetTreatmentAsTIFFButtonToVisible():void{
    this.treatmentAsTIFFComponent.setVisible()
}
private toggleGetTreatmentAsTIFFButtonToInvisible():void{
    this.treatmentAsTIFFComponent.setInvisible()
}
```

**site-map-component.html**:

```
<app-treatment-as-tiff></app-treatment-as-tiff>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? (F12)

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you are basically unable to invoke methods belonging to component class `TreatmentAsTIFFComponent` from `SiteMapComponent` component class?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting `visibilityState` of `iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser` in `TreatmentAsTIFFComponent` to false. Set it to true if you want it to be displayed:

```js
export class TreatmentAsTIFFComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  constructor(private synopsServicesProvider:SYNOPSServicesProviderService) { 
    this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser = {} as ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;
    this.iTreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser.visibilityState = true; // <-- HERE!
  }

  ...
}
```

Or you're not calling the `toggleGetTreatmentAsTIFFButtonToVisible` function inside the `SiteMapComponent`. And I'm certain that your reference to your child element of `TreatmentAsTIFFComponent` inside `SiteMapComponent` is not working.

Here's how you get the reference of `TreatmentAsTIFFComponent` inside `SiteMapComponent`:

```js
import {
    ...
    ViewChild,
    ...
} from '@angular/core';

...

@Component({
    ...
})
export class SiteMapComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(TreatmentAsTIFFComponent) treatmentAsTIFFComponent: TreatmentAsTIFFComponent;

...

    private toggleGetTreatmentAsTIFFButtonToVisible():void{
        this.treatmentAsTIFFComponent.setVisible()
    }
    private toggleGetTreatmentAsTIFFButtonToInvisible():void{
        this.treatmentAsTIFFComponent.setInvisible()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a method in the child component from the parent component, you can use `@ViewChild` decorator,

The `@ViewChild` is being used to inject a reference to `TreatmentAsTIFFComponent` so that the `SiteMapComponent` can use it in its template, in order to call the public methods of the latter.

- In your site-map.component.ts file,

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TreatmentAsTIFFComponent } from '../treatment-as-tiff/treatment-as-tiff.component';

export interface ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser {
  visibilityState: boolean
}

iTreatmentAsTIFFButtonVisibilityPasser: ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;

constructor() {
  this.iTreatmentAsTIFFButtonVisibilityPasser = {} as ITreatmentAsTIFFVisibilityPasser;
  this.iTreatmentAsTIFFButtonVisibilityPasser.visibilityState = false
}

export class SiteMapComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(TreatmentAsTIFFComponent) treatmentAsTIFFComponent: TreatmentAsTIFFComponent;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  toggleGetTreatmentAsTIFFButtonToVisible(): void {
    this.treatmentAsTIFFComponent.setVisible()
  }

}
```

**Note**: The reference to `treatmentAsTIFFComponent` in `SiteMapComponent` will only be available once the view of the parent component is completely initialized.